# Issue with System.Uri

Tags: c#, uri

I'm having an unexpected behavior with the `System.Uri` class.
When an instance of `System.Uri` is created, and the `UrlString` has some patterns like `...`, or `...#`, or `.#`, the `System.Uri` removes all repeated `.` characters.

This is weird, but I believe this behavior is based on RFC 2396.

The problem begins when I try to download the HTML from this URL: http://www.submarino.com.br/produto/1/23853463/mundo+segundo+steve+jobs,+o:+as+frases+mais+inspiradoras+...

and the `System.Uri` removes all the repeated `.`s. As the web site doesn't recognize the "New URL," it redirects to the rriginal URL. Then a "System.Net.WebException: Too many automatic redirections were attempted" is thrown and the page is never reached.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to remove that particular attribute. Use this before your `Uri` call:

```
MethodInfo getSyntax = typeof(UriParser).GetMethod("GetSyntax", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
FieldInfo flagsField = typeof(UriParser).GetField("m_Flags", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if (getSyntax != null && flagsField != null)
{
    foreach (string scheme in new[] { "http", "https" })
    {
        UriParser parser = (UriParser)getSyntax.Invoke(null, new object[] { scheme });
        if (parser != null)
        {
            int flagsValue = (int)flagsField.GetValue(parser);
            // Clear the CanonicalizeAsFilePath attribute
            if ((flagsValue & 0x1000000) != 0)
                flagsField.SetValue(parser, flagsValue & ~0x1000000);
        }
    }
}
```

It has been reported to [Connect before](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/386695/system-ur).

Comment: Disadvantage of this is that it requires full trust and that future updates of .NET Framework could possibly break this code :-(

Comment: @Ňuf - That's a good point. Unfortunately, I haven't seen another solution to this (hopefully someone else has) and it seems like a deep bug within the framework.

Comment: Yes a bug. @keyboardP I was thinking on new implementation of HttpWebRequest, using String instead of System.Uri. What do you think?

Comment: HttpWebRequest uses the same System.Uri rules internally, so if you use that and pass a string (presumably with `WebRequest.Create`), it will still convert it to a `Uri`.

Comment: @keyboardP I'm thinking on reimplement the HttpWebRequest, using Sockets, do you I can have a better performace? I'm doing a crawler. :D thanks!

Comment: Depending on how much of HttpWebRequest yuo want to reimplement, I guess you could. I'm no expert on it, but this article might help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13486/A-Simple-Crawler-Using-C-Sockets